# Convert a custom time string to minutes with sign

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to convert a string like

```
"UTC - 9:30 hours"
```

to minutes.

Something like:

```
var date = "UTC - 9 : 10 hours";
date = date.replace("UTC",'').replace("hours",'').replace(/\s+/g, '');
var hours = parseInt( date.split(":")[0] );
var minutes = parseInt ( date.split(":")[1] || 0 );
var sign = hours / Math.abs(hours);
var totalMinutes = ( hours * 60 ) + ( sign * minutes );
```

Can there be an easier way using any regexp? Just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be patient...is it too trivial something like this?

```
string input = "UTC - 9:30 hours";
Match m = Regex.Match(input, @"(?<sign>-?)\s?(?<hours>\d+)\s?:\s?(?<minutes>\d+)");
int sign = m.Groups["sign"].Value == "-" ? -1 : 1;
int hours = int.Parse(m.Groups["hours"].Value);
int minutes = int.Parse(m.Groups["minutes"].Value);
int totalMinutes = (hours * 60 + minutes)*sign;
```

oh sorry...you talked about javascript. I posted a c# code..well never mind then.
Anyway the regular expression remains valid.

But to answer your question, no it's not easier at all as you can see.

p.s.: I handled the sign in a different way just because I didn't understand your point, and there are lots of `?` operators just to allow a looser pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply:

```
var take     = "UTC - 9:30 hours".split(' ')[2].split(':');
var minutes  = parseFloat(take[0])*60 + parseFloat(take[1]);

alert(minutes); // 570
```

---

also : `var minutes  = Number(take[0])*60 + Number(take[1]);`

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/itasur/2/edit)*

Comment: @Raminson - Hey thanks! I'll be away some time (I'll be watching but not posting), I almost ruined my life. (see my profile description...) Thumbs up! BTW, nice answers Raminson I'll keep following your nice progress!

Comment: Why Bro? ruined? What do you mean? what makes you feel this way? What you have written is what I think and believe, Life is Fight, Fight for defending and defeating the weaknesses, As Nietzsche says What doesn't destroy me, Makes me Stronger.

Comment: @Raminson it's about *family*. +1 for Nietzsche :)